# Codeigniter 3 Session error

Tags: windows-10, codeigniter-3, wampserver, php-7.1

Heloo, I have this error:

> Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::open, SessionHandlerInterface::read) in D:\wamp64\www\has\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49

I have tried proposed solutions from forums and I have replaced the system folder of CI 3 but still no luck. Restarting apache fixes the problem temporary. But after a while, it still comes back. Here is my working environment:

**Windows 10 64 bit Pro; Wamp Server 3.1.0; PHP Version 7.1.10; Codeigniter 3.1.6;**

What is very interesting, i have two other projects on this Wamp Server that are on Codeigniter 2, and they dont seem to have this problem. I noticed this when i switched from PHP5 to PHP7. Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Some one reported similar issue on Github:
[PHP >= 7 session problem](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5118),
which link to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723614/3008457), turn off `opcache` in `php.ini`:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Hope this is the solution you are looking for, currently I don't have the setup to reproduce the error.

Comment: I already saw that solution, but opcache is already disabled in my configuration. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::open, SessionHandlerInterface::close) using Codeigniter**

The one of the reason for this error is recursive function calling with no ending.