# Mad PHP - Randomly, Sometimes Some Built-in Functions Becomes Undefined While Other Times Ramaining Defined

Tags: php, apache

[Update 18.01.14]
This question was marked a duplicate of [Intermittent PHP Abstract Class Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error) . However, they are different in much of the bug appearance as follows.

1. That link only have `contains x abstract method` error. But mine have more types, and the errors are more weird (see the errors below, even containing some control characters).
2. In that link, the questioner said disabling `opcache` will make it happen less frequently. But in my case I did never enable the opcache but these bugs happened.

[/Update]

I am using `Apache`, `PHP`, `Laravel` to develop my web backend. But several times a day, errors will occur saying some php **built-in functions are undefined**, but **at other time when it is not mad, these functions are obviously defined and work well**. (So it is **not** because I call something really undefined!)

There are even stranger things. The "undefined" things can be a php function, system constant, or even some strange strings which look like regex, or even **control characters** in ASCII! The examples are as follows.

1. `Declaration of PDO::() should be compatible with PDO::?)[CHAR1][CHAR2]` where the `[CHAR1]` and `[CHAR2]` are `SOH`and `ETX` in ASCII.
2. `Call to undefined method #^\\{\\w+\\}#::format()`
3. `Call to undefined method DateTime::format()`
4. `Undefined class constant 'PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION'`
5. (Other types of errors) `Class Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement::errorInfo, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement::closeCursor)`

Here are some more information: It usually happens every several hours, but can happen in half an hour or do not happen for half a day. My server handles about 1 http GET or POST request every second from one of the 6 remote machines.

This annoys me for a very long time and I would appreciate it if anyone could help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: It can be cause of wrong name spacing, If you want to use function / class from global scope - you should use \ (back slash) before calling, for example \PDO:: instead of PDO::

Comment: @AlexSlipknot However, it works pretty well during most of the time, and without modifying any code, it suddenly goes mad and throws this error.

Comment: Well, it will be great if there is some stack trace for those errors. So you can get exact problem

Comment: I was bitten by a variant of this behaviour, and the solution *might* be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48250183/1428679

Comment: @LSerni But the problem exists **when I was not using opcache at all**. But anyway thank you for your suggestion and I will try it. :)

Comment: Do you have any kind of caching or "make-php-go-faster" trick installed? The behaviour I got - and looks like the one you reported - was due to a class being loaded which was **not** the class we intended, but "similar enough" for the system not to realize this. Your error #4 hints at PDO not being loaded, while #5 hints at *two* different PDOStatement classes existing. Also, `format` does exist in standard DateTime, and your error #3 strongly hints at a different DateTime being in existence in the same namespace.

Comment: @LSerni Ha! I think your statement is quite strong, and I will try it out in a few days. Thank you very much! :)