# Codeigniter error i tried restart apache and then its shoving same issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in C:\xampp\htdocs\First\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49

If i have large system it is difficult to overwrite all things.
some other solution available ?

Comment: You should write some code what are you doing with code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: I have deleted my answer I think This will not be the correct solution.

Comment: You are using class `CI_Session_files_driver` with implements `SessionHandlerInterface`, Right?

Comment: Try to restart the Apache once

Comment: i restart so many times but its showing same error.

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: version is PHP 7.0.22

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error

Comment: try to install the latest Codeigniter version.