# Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have some problems with CodeIgniter, this error is from system file and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Yachi\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Error

    Message: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read)

    Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

    Line Number: 49

    Backtrace:
```

I read some articles about this, but it doesn't help to find out the answer. Thanks.

Comment: try using session driver as database

Comment: Check following link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is your actual setup with sessions. Can you post your session config data. What version of CI and what version of PHP are you running on.

Comment: Sorry because of the delay, I just set up session_driver with files, I use CodeIgniter 3.1.5 and PHP 7.1.4. If I change session_driver as database, it will be more errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class CI\_Session\_files\_driver contains 1 abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896271/fatal-error-class-ci-session-files-driver-contains-1-abstract-method)

Comment: Which articles did you read?

Comment: I read this article but I don't know how to fix, what should I fix?

Comment: So you replaced the file as was suggested?

Comment: Yes, I replaced system file but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug seems about windows+php7. Not for CI

Restarting apache server can be a temporary solution. But you should repeat it every time crash happen.

I recommend to use linux enviornment 
or Downgrade php version to 5.x until it solve.

Related links I found:

[PHP 7, Symfony 3: Fatal error 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088683/php-7-symfony-3-fatal-error-1-abstract-method-and-must-therefore-be-declared-a)

https://www.drupal.org/node/2711155

https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=250966&sid=96ef58aaeb7fe142a7dcdfd506a8683f